# How should embeddedmodelfields appear in django-nonrel admin?

Tags: mongodb, django-admin, django-nonrel

In using **Django-nonrel**, I have used ***ListField*** and ***EmbeddedModelFields***.

But when I register the models with *admin.py*, I do not see any separate input fields for fields in a model which is "embedded" in to another model.

I see that using *models.ForeignKey* gives the result but with a loss of ***EmbeddedModelFields***.

I am using the latest(git) version of **Django-nonrel**, **djangotoolbox**, and **django-mongodb-engine**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if we want to do this, make a custom widgets to get "inline input boxes" and a form subclass to get the desired fields in admin panel.

Rather add testdata through mongo shell and see how it is displayed in admin.